# Asymptotic expansion of the floor function at infinity

Tags: calculus, limits, asymptotics

Is it possible to study the behavior of the floor function at infinity by estimating its growth?

The floor function has countably many discontinuities at integers, so I'm afraid that these discontinuities will somehow make it hard to study its behavior.

We all have seen in a first calculus course that $$\lim_{n \to \infty} \lfloor n \rfloor = n + \text{ other negligible terms }$$

But is it possible to make this estimation more accurate as $n \to \infty$?

The reason that I'm asking this is because of this post of mine in [here](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/711096/accumulation-points-of-sqrtn-sqrtm-m-n-in-mathbbn).

I'm trying to show that the following limit exists and is equal to $r$:

$$\lim_{n \to \infty} \sqrt{\lfloor (n+r)^2 \rfloor+1}-\sqrt{n^2}$$

I've already shown that:

$$\lim_{n \to \infty} \sqrt{\lfloor (n+r)^2 \rfloor+1}-\sqrt{n^2} = \lim_{n \to \infty}\frac{\lfloor (n+r)^2 \rfloor+1-n^2}{\sqrt{\lfloor (n+r)^2 \rfloor+1}+\sqrt{n^2}} = \lim_{n \to \infty} \frac{\lfloor (n+r)^2 \rfloor - n^2}{2n}$$

But now I'm stuck because now I need an asymptotic expansion of $\lfloor x \rfloor$ at infinity that gives better estimates.

Any ideas are appreciated.

Comment: Try using the fact that $$\forall x \, \big(x-1 \leq \lfloor x \rfloor \leq x\big).$$

Comment: Your first equality is wrong and the limit is $+\infty$.

Comment: @SamiBenRomdhane: The limit is not $+\infty$ unless I have made some typos. Use wolfram alpha and you'll see that it DOES converge.

Comment: @math.n00b no, it does not. [This](https://www.wolframalpha.com/input/?i=lim%28floor%28x%29%2C+x-%3E+infinity%29) is Wolframalpha.

Comment: @dadexix86: Are you kidding me? I'm talking about this one: $\lim_{n \to \infty} \sqrt{\lfloor (n+r)^2 \rfloor+1}-\sqrt{n^2}$. Pay attention please. Go type that formula in wolframalpha and choose n as large as you may, you see that the given sequence as a function of $r$ converges to $r$. This is so obvious from calculations by wolfram that I doubt it diverges! However, if someone insists that it diverges, cool, then prove that it diverges if you can!

Comment: @SamiBenRomdhane: Ah, now I see what you mean. You meant $\lim_{n \to \infty} \lfloor n \rfloor = n$. I thought you were referring to the limit in problem. Yes, I meant that as a limit equality, not an actual equality. I'll edit my post.

Comment: That converges (and I'm tryong to prove it). But that is the *second* equation. The *first* equation that you wrote (the one that @SamiBenRomdhane pointed out) is wrong (or at least bad written).

Comment: @dadexix86: Yeah, just now I understood what he meant. Pardon me.

Comment: $n$ is, it seems, supposed to be an integer. Then $\lfloor (n+r)^2\rfloor - n^2 = \lfloor n^2 + 2nr + r^2\rfloor - n^2 = \lfloor 2nr + r^2\rfloor$, and $$r + \frac{r^2-1}{2n} = \frac{2nr+r^2-1}{2n} < \frac{\lfloor 2nr + r^2\rfloor}{2n} \leqslant \frac{2nr+r^2}{2n} = r + \frac{r^2}{2n}.$$ You can read off that the limit is $r$ from that.

Comment: @DanielFischer: Thank you Daniel.It's sad that I couldn't see this on my own :( It means that I still need to practice more and more. However, is it possible to prove/disprove that $f_n(r) = \sqrt{\lfloor (n+r)^2 \rfloor+1}-\sqrt{n^2}$ converges "uniformly" to $f(r)=r$? Because it seems so from wolframalpha and I'm still wondering if $\lim_{n \to \infty} \lfloor n \rfloor \approx n$ could be improved to a better asymptotic expansion.

Comment: It can't converge uniformly on all of $\mathbb{R}$. For any $N$, choose $\lvert r\rvert > ((5^{N+2})!)!$ and the $n$ is insignificantly small in comparison. The convergence is locally uniform, however, on every interval $[-R,R]$, $f_n(r) \to r$ uniformly.

Comment: @DanielFischer: Sorry if I ask too many questions, it's because I'm still a freshman and I don't know much mathematics yet, but would you explain why you take $\lvert r\rvert > ((5^{N+2})!)!$? Why did you choose that number? How did it come to you? And how do you want to show this number disproves uniform convergence?

Comment: No particular reason for that number. I just wanted something much much larger than $n$. But I didn't pay attention, for large $r$, $\sqrt{\lfloor (n+r)^2\rfloor+1}$ is very close to $n+r$, so that's fine. It could indeed converge uniformly, I must take a look.

Comment: Are you interested only in non-negative $r$, or all $r\in\mathbb{R}$? (If also negative $r$, choose $r = -n$ to get $\sqrt{\lfloor (n+r)^2\rfloor+1} - \sqrt{n^2} = 1-n$, which is $1$ away from $r$.)